# How to apply regex on a string based on a rule in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which looks like this

```
str = "<span> list: <mat> </span> && <span> see: how much <mat> </span> && <span> with: <mat> = '<pok>'</span>"
```

Now I want to replace all `<` and `>` with `&lt` and `&gt` respectively. But I also want to ensure the `<span> </span>` tags are not touched. This is what I do currently

```
str = str.replace(/\</g,"&lt;").replace(/\>/g,"&gt;")
```

But it replaces every instances of `<` and `>` with `&lt` and `&gt`. Can a `regex` have a rule that except `<span>` tags everything else needs to be replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what browsers you're supporting, you can match around your `span` tags by using negative lookaheads and lookbehinds:

```
str.replace(/<(?!(\/?span))/g,'&lt;').replace(/(?<!\/?span)>/g, '&gt;')
```

`?!` is a negative lookahead and tells the RegEx engine to only match if the following text does not match that expression (e.g. "If the next bit of text after `<` is `span` or `/span`, skip it).

`?<!` is a negative lookbehind and tells the RegEx engine to only match if the preceding text does not match (e.g. "If the text before `>` is `span` or `/span`, skip it).

[Mozilla has a summary of browser support for lookaheads and lookbehinds.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Browser_compatibility) They are fairly well supported now, with the exception of FireFox.

Answer (score 1):

I'd match `<[^>]+>` (a `<`, eventually followed by a `>`), then use a replacer function to escape the brackets if the current match isn't `<span>` or `</span>`:

```js
const str = "<span> list: <mat> </span> && <span> see: how much <mat> </span> && <span> with: <mat> = '<pok>'</span>";
const escape = str => str
  .replace(/</g, '&lt')
  .replace(/>/g, '&gt');

const result = str.replace(
  /<[^>]+>/g,
  match => (match === '<span>' || match === '</span>') ? match : escape(match)
);
console.log(result);
```